# Apache CXF-JMS 3.0 and Spring configuration

Tags: java, cxf, spring-jms

I am trying to configure JMS connection caching and consumer concurrency with Spring to perform some load tests. The application context xml is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core" 
    xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:soap="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="amqConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
        <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://172.18.2.100:8080"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="clientCachingConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
        <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="amqConnectionFactory"/>
        <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="20"/>
        <property name="cacheProducers" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="clientContainerListener" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="clientCachingConnectionFactory" />
        <property name="destinationName" value="test.load.outside.multispeak.ch.queue" />
    </bean>   

    <jaxws:client 
        id="load-test-multispeak-ch-client"
        xmlns:ns="http://www.multispeak.org/Version_4.1_Release"
        serviceClass="org.multispeak.version_4_1_6.CH.CHServerSoap"
        serviceName="ns:CH_Server"
        endpointName="ns:CH_ServerSoap"
        address="jms://"
        wsdlLocation="classpath:CH_Server.wsdl">
        <jaxws:features>
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryFeature">
                <constructor-arg index="0" ref="clientCachingConnectionFactory"/>
            </bean>
        </jaxws:features>
    </jaxws:client>

    <bean id="serverCachingConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
        <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="amqConnectionFactory"/>
        <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="20"/>
        <property name="cacheConsumers" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="serverContainerListener" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="serverCachingConnectionFactory" />
        <property name="destinationName" value="test.load.outside.multispeak.ch.queue" />
        <property name="cacheLevel" value="3" />
        <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="10" />
        <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="50" />
    </bean>   

    <jaxws:endpoint 
        id="load-test-multispeak-ch-server"
        xmlns:tns="http://www.multispeak.org/Version_4.1_Release"
        implementor="pt.fraunhofer.outside.multispeak.ch.server.CHServerSoapImpl"
        serviceName="tns:CH_Server" 
        endpointName="tns:CH_ServerSoap" 
        publish="false"
        address="jms://"
        wsdlLocation="classpath:CH_Server.wsdl">
        <jaxws:features>
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature"/>
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryFeature">
                <constructor-arg index="0" ref="serverCachingConnectionFactory"/>
            </bean>
        </jaxws:features>
    </jaxws:endpoint>
```

According to CXF documentation, from 3.0, a `ConnectionFactoryFeature` should be used instead of a `JMSConfigFeature`, which is deprecated (http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jms-transport.html). I was following the examples provided at http://cxf.apache.org/scalable-cxf-applications-using-jms-transport.html, but the documentation there seems to refer to CXF versions earlier than 3.0, because `JMSConfiguration` class in 3.0 does not have caching or concurrency capabilites (no setters/getters). So, I was trying to use Spring to achieve the same result, but without success. The very same documentation refers to Spring `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` as a container for caching and concurrency configuration, but I was not able to find examples of this with CXF integration, only for pure JMS. Also, `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` has a setter to register a JMS `MessageListener`. In case of CXF, I found that that listener is created and managed by CXF runtime and is not provided provided by the application.

Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you allready fix this problem?

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27869370/apache-cxf-3-jms-support-for-multiple-concurrent-consumers/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you can not set concurrent consumers for CXF 3. I did some performance tests with ActiveMQ and found the performance with CXF 3 is equal to CXF 2 or even better.

The reason is that we now use a MessageListener approach instead of the polling that spring did.

[See my website for the performance tests](http://liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/2014/03/28/Revisiting+JMS+performance.+Improvements+in+CXF+3.0.0).

Comment: This is a bit outdated now. In the upcoming CXF 3.1 you can now again use concurrentConsumers. While the performance of the MessageListener approach was good for a fast service it was quite bad for a long running service. It will work with JMSConfiguration as well as with the URI based configuration.

Answer (score 0):

We need to be able to tune concurrent and maximum consumers so we can handle our message load. The constraint is in speed of message processing by our applications; CXF is not the bottleneck.  Are there plans to re-introduce these parameters in CXF? Can we configure CXF to use a configured DefaultMessageListenerContainer?