# Apache CXF 3 JMS support for multiple concurrent consumers

Tags: web-services, soap, jms, cxf

CXF 3.0 removed support for configuration of concurrent consumers.  I'm new to CXF's JMS support, but in CXF 3.0, JMS-based SOAP services are being single threaded: when I add two SOAP messages to a queue, the second message does not begin processing until the first message is completed.  Am I doing something wrong, or is this a limitation in CXF's JMS implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right and doing it correctly, CXF 3.0 does not support concurrent consumers. A few e-mails were exchanged recently in the mailing list about this. You can see it [here](http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/CXF-3-0-1-doesn-t-have-concurrentConsumers-td5749534.html#a5753084). However it seems that CXF 3.0.3 was fixed. Check out the [issue in JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-6199).

You can try to implement pure asynchronous behaviour on the server side by explicitly implementing the async versions of the methods and then annotate the sync methods with @UseAsyncMethod.